# MySQL Selecting things where a condition on a row is met 2 or more times, but showing the two or more results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If I use `GROUP BY` then I will get just 1 row per group. For example

```
Sessions table: SessionId (other things)

Actions table: ActionId, SessionId, (other things)
```

With:

```
SELECT S.*, A.* FROM ActionList A JOIN SessionList S ON A.SessionId
    =S.SessionId
WHERE 1 /*various criteria to filter*/

ORDER BY S.SessionId DESC, ActionId DESC;
```

Thus showing me the most recent session at the top. Now I want to look at only sessions with 2 or more actions.

If I use `GROUP BY A.SessionId` then I can get `COUNT(ActionId)` and use `HAVING` to look at rows only with the required count, but I wont get both rows (or  more) rows, just the one.

I suspect I can do this by `JOIN`ing a table with SessionIds and the count of action IDs but I'm fairly new to joins (I could do this via a subquery any `ANY`).

If a view would help, I would create a view of the form:

```
SELECT SessionId, COUNT(*) FROM Actions GROUP BY SessionId;
```

Or put this in brackets and `JOIN` on it (but I confess I'd have to loop up 3 table joins)

What is the neatest way to do this?

Also is this where "Foreign keys" come into play? That'd probably stop the "ambiguity errors" I get if I don't qualify SessionId. I've avoided them for fear of `TRIGGER`s, I also didn't know about JOINs and just used subqueries until recently. I've realised it is stupid to avoid things that were added to help.

**Additionally** I'm quite timid with joins because I know what it does, well worst case. If I JOIN on a table with m rows, and another with n I end up with m*n rows. That could be VERY large! I'm dealing with large tables (as in: schema wont fit in RAM large) so that is quite scary. I do know MySQL optimises well (able to move stuff from `HAVING` to `WHERE` and so forth) but still!

Comment: Do not mistake `JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` (aka Cartesian Product).

Comment: A plain (i.e. inner) join will only include the combinations which satisfy the matching condition (the `ON` clause).

Comment: I've just done 3 joins (it was the first thing I guessed, sorry my feelings for PHP seem to have tainted my view :P). I feel silly for posting this question now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at sessions with two or more actions, then use a join:

```
select sl.*
from SessionList sl join
     (select SessionId, count(*) as cnt
      from Actions
      group by SessionId
     ) a
     on sl.SessionId = a.SessionId and cnt > 1;
```